# Selenium/Java POI: NullPointerException is thrown

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi

When I execute SignIn_Action in the below code I am getting nullpointer exception in `ActionKeywords.input("txtbx_UserName", sUserName1);` 
not sure what could be the problem, Help please. 
Where as this is working fine with this code `driver.findElement(objMap.getbjectLocator("txtbx_UserName")).sendKeys(sUserName1);`

```
public class SignIn_Action {

    public static void Execute(WebDriver driver) throws Exception{

        objectMap objMap = new objectMap();

        String sUserName1 = DriverScript.execute_TestCase("sUserName1");
        String sPassword1 = DriverScript.execute_TestCase("sPassword1");

   ** This is where the code is returning null**
        ActionKeywords.input("txtbx_UserName", sUserName1);
        ActionKeywords.input("txtbx_Password", sPassword1);


   ** If I use the below code then it's working properly**
        /*  driver.findElement(objMap.getbjectLocator("txtbx_UserName"))
           .sendKeys(sUserName1);
            driver.findElement(objMap.getbjectLocator("txtbx_Password"))
           .sendKeys(sPassword1);
            Login_Page.btn_LogIn(driver).submit();
            Thread.sleep(2000); */

    }
}

public class ActionKeywords {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void input(String object, String data){

        objectMap objMap = new objectMap();

            WebElement input = driver.findElement(objMap.getbjectLocator(object));
            input.sendKeys(data);           
    }
}

public class objectMap {

    public By getbjectLocator(String locatorName)
    {
        String locatorProperty = OR.getProperty(locatorName);
        System.out.println(locatorProperty.toString());
        String locatorType = locatorProperty.split(":")[0];
        String locatorValue = locatorProperty.split(":")[1];

        By locator = null;
        switch(locatorType)
        {
        case "xpath":
            locator = By.xpath(locatorValue);
            break;
        case "id":
            locator = By.id(locatorValue);
            break;
        case "name":
            locator = By.name(locatorValue);
            break;
        case "cssSelector":
            locator = By.cssSelector(locatorValue);
            break;
        case "linkText":
            locator = By.linkText(locatorValue);
            break;
        case "partialLinkText":
            locator = By.partialLinkText(locatorValue);
            break;
        case "tagName":
            locator = By.tagName(locatorValue);
            break;
        }
        return locator;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the stacktrace. I suspect the NPE is initially caused by the code line `WebElement input = driver.findElement(objMap.getbjectLocator(object));` in `ActionKeywords.input` because `driver` is `NULL` there. At least your showed code does not setting `driver` to something else than `NULL` in `ActionKeywords`.

Comment: Perfect Axel Richter.. you are correct. I have fixed it.